# Javascript implementation of Java's Random class that will generate same sequences with same seed

Tags: javascript, java, random, generator

1st I did multiple searches here and via google trying to find this so sorry ahead of time if I didn't use the right search terms to find it.

I'm rewriting some legacy Java code into Javascript and I've got it all working except for pseudo random number generator... I need the Javascript version of this code to have repeatable output via both the Java and Javascript versions of this code as such I can't use Javascript's RN generator... I also can't change the legacy code to use another RN generator....

So I'm hoping someone had been in the similar situation and has already done this and written/ported Java's RNG into Javascript?

Is it even possible given javascripts bit wise operators only work with a 32 bit word while Java's RNG is based on 64 bit seed... obviously would need two variables each holding 1/2 the seed...

---

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

- Java's setSeed does

  ```
  (seed ^ 0x5DEECE66DL) & ((1L << 48) - 1)
  ```
- and next does

  ```
  (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1)
  ```
- and returning

  ```
  (int)(seed >>> (48 - bits)).
  ```

Comment: It should at least be possible - I've previously written code to pack and unpack IEEE-754 `double` values in JS.

Comment: Your assumption is correct: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: A slight complication is that the multiplication by `0x5DEECE66DL` even when just looking at the bottom 32 bits could create an intermediate result that exceeds the 52 or so bits that you can use for accurate integer storage in a JS `Number`.  There's no native 64 bit integer math in JS at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created an ES6 class that in my tests produces the same results as the `java.util.Random` class.   So far I've only implemented the `.nextInt()` public method but it's implemented via the `.next()` protected method so the other public methods should be easy to implement:

https://gist.github.com/raybellis/4c15a1746724be7bd03964e9d03e0c75

**EDIT** an enhanced version of this is now available as an NPM:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/java-random

Comment: Looks like I was premature saying it works perfectly (which it did in basic tests using a fixed bound)... but while testing actual application against the legacy java application the JS Random returns a different value from actual JDK at the same iteration (after both seeded the same) whenever the "bound" being passed in to nextInt is a power of 2.  The difference between Java's RNG nextInt(bound) and the JS one is that latter doesn't check if bound is a power of two and treat that case differently(ie. "return (bound * (long)next(31)) >> 31").

Comment: fwiw seed=7937 and for( i  of 63..2 ) r = nextInt(i) reproduces it.

Comment: Fixed in v0.2.2, although I'm unsure if it'll produce accurate results for very high values of n=2^x

Comment: It seems OK - tested with `let r = new Random(7937);
for (i = 1; i < 31; ++i) {
 console.log(r.nextInt(1 << i));
}`

Comment: @JeffM I've now implemented almost all of the rest of `java.util.Random`, with the exception being the functions that return a `Stream` of numbers within the specified range.